# iOS - remove a digit in text field on button click

Tags: ios

I want to remove a character from a text field on button click. This is working for me when I remove character from the last position, But unable to remove character from a random position.
Can any one help me out fixing this one

**EDIT**

Currently i have:

```
- (IBAction)clearTextKeyPressed:(id)sender {
  NSString *enteredText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.targetTextField.text];
  if ( [enteredText length] > 0) {
      enteredText = [enteredText substringToIndex:[enteredText length] - 1];
      self.targetTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", enteredText];
      [self.numericGridKeypadDelegate textFieldDidChange:self.targetTextField];        
  }
}
```

Using this i am able to delete character at last position, also i want to delete character from any position

**Note**
Character is a digit from 0-9 only

Comment: Should it delete the character at position or backspace?

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Comment: it should delete that character

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I would make it into a category for NSString though.

```
- (NSString*)deleteCharacterAtPosition:(int)position inString:(NSString*)myString {
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [myString mutableCopy];
    [mutableString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(position, 1)];
    return mutableString;
}
```

If you don't want to delete any digits. Then, you should check to see if that position has a non-digit character before calling this function.

Or you can do this:

```
- (NSString*)deleteCharacterAtPosition:(int)position inString:(NSString*)myString {
    NSRange range;
    range.location = position;
    range.length = 1;
    return [test stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

This is how to check to see if the position is a digit:

```
- (bool)isCharacterAtPositionADigit:(int)position inString:(NSString*)myString {
    unichar c = [myString characterAtIndex:position];
    NSCharacterSet *numericSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    if ([numericSet characterIsMember:c]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now here is what you want:

```
- (IBAction)clearTextKeyPressed:(id)sender {
  NSString *enteredText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.targetTextField.text];
  int positionToDelete = 3;
  if ( [enteredText length] > 0 && [enteredText length] >= positionToDelete) {
      if (![self isCharacterAtPositionADigit:positionToDelete inString:enteredText])
          return;
      NSString* finalText = [self deleteCharacterAtPosition:positionToDelete inString:enteredText];
      self.targetTextField.text = finalText;
      [self.numericGridKeypadDelegate textFieldDidChange:self.targetTextField];        
  }
}
```

Comment: This is more precise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"a" withString:@"b"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
NSString *string = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 1) withString:@"A"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace with blank stirng. Like this..

```
NSString *string = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1) withString:@""];
```

For example see this example

```
 NSString *str = @"Hello";

    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"e"];

    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"String after replacement %@",str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but It is removing first character only

Comment: with the help of NSMakeRange i am trying to get position of the character in text field

Comment: Pass your text range in NSMakeRange method.

Answer (score 0):

NSCharacterSet are cool

```
 NSString* testString = @"This is buggy, buggy says hi, this is buggy when a car comes by.";
 NSString* firstCharacter = [testString substringToIndex:1];
 NSString* lastCharacter = [testString substringWithRange:NSRangeMake(testString.length - 1, 1)];
 NSCharacterSet* customCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", firstCharacter, lastCharacter]];
 testString = [testString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:customCharacterSet];
```

Comment: when you click a button, you would like to remove the last character of a textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Fix this using getting offset of a digit which i want to delete:

```
        UITextRange *selRange = self.targetTextField.selectedTextRange;
        UITextPosition *selStartPos = selRange.start;
        NSInteger idx = [self.targetTextField offsetFromPosition:self.targetTextField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:selStartPos];
        if (idx != 0) {
          enteredText =  [enteredText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(idx-1, 1) withString:@""];
          self.targetTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", enteredText];
        }
```

Thanks all for help.